# How to assess GEE quality and fit, e.g. by residuals(?)

Tags: goodness-of-fit, generalized-estimating-equations, geepack

In contrast for generalized linear models (for **GLM**, there is e.g. AIC and null vs. residual deviance), I could not find such criteria implemented in R to judge my generalized equation (**GEE**) models.
Is it appropriate to look at

- residuals vs predicted values scatterplot?
- normal distribution of residuals (e.g. QQ plot)?

I am also happy to learn a better way to assess GEE models (available in an R package, or easily possible to calculate on my own if you show me how).
So far, I am using `geepack::geeglm` (or `gee::gee`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the quasi-likelihood under the independence model criterion (QIC; Pan, 2001) to assess the model fit. It's implemented in geepack. However, caution is advised when employing QIC and its use should not be routine, see Wang et al. (2015).

```
library(geepack)
data(ohio)
fit.e <- geeglm(resp ~ age + smoke + age:smoke, id=id, data=ohio,
             family=binomial, corstr="exchangeable")
fit.a <- update(fit,corstr="ar1")
QIC(fit.e)
QIC(fit.a)
```

Pan 2001: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.0006-341X.2001.00120.x

Wang et al. 2015: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/sta4.95